# How to click in a view with a Robotium automation script?

Tags: android, automation, robotium

There is a screen where we are searching for text and after that searched view shown. We have to click on that view (marked green on screenshot) to go for next page. I am not able to click on that view.

[image]

Comment: Please do not beg for urgency or special treatment in your questions. Not only does it attract downvotes, but it causes edit work as well - what use is your temporary urgency to readers six months hence?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to know if you are using `Listview`.

You need to notify the `BaseAdapter` after you searched the text. Then you have to refresh the listview array by calling `Notifydatasetchanged()`.

Answer (score 0):

clickONText()

clickINScrenn(x,y) or something like that